# Single click on a button does not show dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 table. The table shows records fetched from DB. The last column has a with with gear icon and upon clicking it a bootstrap dropdown menu is displayed.

Each `<tr>` element has some a data attribute shown below:

```
<tr data-href="http://localhost/enterprise/dashboard/staff/6">
...
</tr>
```

Now, the dropdown in the last column does not show on single click. If it is clicked twice, it then displays the dropdown. What could be the reason?

Comment: You need provide all the code needed to replicate your problem.

Comment: Can you please share the associated JavaScript code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem? If you don't have any custom code, could you please specify exactly what Bootstrap references you have?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have replicated it in jquery fiddle. The link is https://jsfiddle.net/9k56nuLm/3/.  Here if you please check the last column, there is a button with gear icon. It pops up a dropdown instantly. But when it does not happen in case of my WAMP server. Thanks again for the help.